# Calculating age from SSN

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working with a project in SSRS

In Database i have a column called X and in this column , i have Social Security Numbers for all employees and all numbers look like this with out any ( - or /) example 1111111111 (DDMMYYXXXX).

My question is ,how can i write a sql to just select 6 first number and then minus current time and in end give me age of employees. Can someone please point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

So far the sql i wrote look like this:

```
create function dbo.birthdate_from_cpr(@cpr varchar(10))
returns date
as
begin
  declare @year char(2) = substring(@cpr, 5, 2),
          @month char(2) = substring(@cpr, 3, 2),
          @day char(2) = substring(@cpr, 1, 2),
          @century char(2)



  if right(datepart(yy, getdate()), 2) < @year
    set @century = left(datepart(yy, getdate()) - 100, 2)
  else
    set @century = left(datepart(yy, getdate()), 2)


  return convert(date, @century + @year + @month + @day, 120)
end
go

select dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('1312761234'),
       dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('0101041234'),
       age = datediff(yy, dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('1312761234'), getdate())
```

Comment: DATEDIFF(YEAR,CAST(LEFT(colName, 6) AS DATE),GETDATE()))

Comment: LEFT(Users.SSN, 6) what does that look like?

Comment: Can you share your example table data and expected output.

Comment: DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LEFT(Users.SSN, 6)))),GETDATE()) Try this. Might be a bracket problem though

Comment: Is it a safe assumption that no employees are over 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [`left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [`stuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to create a well-formatted string, and [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to change it to a date value, and then it's just [`datediff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Don't be alarmed by the length of the query, It's only the last column you need. I've chosen to show every step in a different column.

```
DECLARE @SSN char(10) = '1309761234'

SELECT  @SSN as OriginalString,
        STUFF(
             STUFF(LEFT(@SSN, 6), 3, 0, '.')
            , 6, 0, '.') As DateString,
       CONVERT(date, 
               STUFF(
                     STUFF(LEFT(@SSN, 6), 3, 0, '.')
               , 6, 0, '.')
       , 4) As Date, -- German, no century - dd.mm.yy
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, 
                    CONVERT(date, 
                            STUFF(LEFT(@SSN, 4), 3, 0, '.') +'.'+
                            CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) / 100 - 1 as char(2)) + 
                            SUBSTRING(@SSN, 5, 2)
                    , 104) 
                 , GETDATE()) As Age
```

Result:

```
OriginalString  DateString  Date                    Age
1309761234      13.09.76    13.09.1976 00:00:00     41
```

And with your query:

```
SELECT Users.Id, Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS Medarbajder,
Users.SSN AS CPRNR, 
CASE WHEN Users.SSN IS NOT NULL THEN
DATEDIFF(YEAR, 
        CONVERT(date, 
                            STUFF(LEFT(Users.SSN, 4), 3, 0, '.') +'.'+
                            CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) / 100 - 1 as char(2)) + 
                            SUBSTRING(Users.SSN, 5, 2)
                    , 104) 
, GETDATE()) 
ELSE
NULL
END As Age,
convert(varchar(10), Paychecks.WorkStartDate, 105) AS StartDato ,
Paychecks.DepartmentName AS Afdelinger

FROM dbo.Paychecks, dbo.Users
WHERE Users.CustomerId=214 AND Users.Id=Paychecks.UserId order by Users.FirstName;
```

Comment: Thanks for all this , But i got error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.

Comment: i get another one : Conversion failed when converting date and time from character string

Comment: Are you sure it's ddmmyy? I don't have your sample data to work with, that's why I've created the sample data myself. The actual lenght of the column is irrelevant as long as it's at least 6 chars long, since we are only interested in the first 6 chars.

Comment: `0101012342` translates to January 1st 2001. [see for yourself.](http://rextester.com/BBI85764) Somewhere in the table there is at least one number that can't be converted with as `ddmmyy`. If you are working on 2012 version or higher, replace the `convert` with `try_convert` and see where you get null values. these are the numbers  that can't be converted.

Comment: Perhaps the null values are the problem then. I've edited my answer to ignore null values.

Comment: Does the column starts with the ddmmyyyy or is there anything before that? perhaps there is a space somewhere before the number? try adding ltrim as well.

Comment: dudde is workiiiing , god bless you , thank you so muchh and if is ok with you, can i have your email adresse or something i can contact with you, if is ok with you,

Comment: Well, first of all, I'm glad I could help. Second, I almost never give out my email. I'm in stackoverflow almost on a daily basis, so if you really want to contant me you can simply write a comment that contains @ZoharPeled and I'll see it.

Comment: it is alright and i understand. thanks a lot again and i will do that.

Comment: Hello Again :)  i have an issue for older folk, there are 5 employees with 70 , 75 years old and when i run the query and look at older folk age's is something like this -29 instead something like this 70.i'll fix the minus with Abs function But i dont how should i fix the numbers !

Comment: The problem is that your year is stated without century (only last 2 digits). This makes sql server assume that anything less then 50 is the current century, but anything over 49 is the previous one. See my edited answer that addresses this issue. Note - this is not perfect - too young people will have ages of old people, but there really is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: Tnx bro , i undestand. i also edit my code with the edit anwser you just posted , i get error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. But if you had same situation like me,what will you do ? or what you suggested to solve this issue ?!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the convert style from 4 to 104. edited my answer once again...

Comment: it's happend again , i get error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Sorry again. I forgot to change the left from 6 to 4. edited again (hopefully for the last time today)

Comment: Just dont kill me :D , its happend again Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: It's not your fault, it's mine. I don't know how but I keep missing silly things when editing my answer. Now I've missed the `+'.'`. fixed it.

Comment: thank you so much bro , i mean it.is working fine.if you have time now, i just have 3 last question to better understand the code.1. wat you done exactly with code to solve the problem for older folk ,can you explain to me please ! i just lit bit confused. 2.if is coming younger people the code will work also for them ?! 3. when i run the query its working fine with out a error But when i scroll down the employees list , suddenly the system ,give me error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time ,i dont get it why !

Comment: 1.I've added the tow century digits of 1900. 2. If anyone was born at 2000+ the age will return wrong. 3. I don't know. Probably something unexpected in the ssn values.

Comment: if is up to me , i have more question about this,if you allow me that i will ask otherwise i dont , beacuse i'm one of those  type should understand things at gone on to next steps and an other reason is i'm front-end developer  and i dont work so deeply with sql server or my sql and back-end ,i've work with kinds of sql but not everyday.But i dont wanna give up on that and i wanna learn more, so can you tell me at least ,wat materials exactly should i looking for to learn and better understandig for example situation like this .

Comment: It's a very broad subject. Basic sql you already know. advanced stuff usually vary between products - my-sql uses different syntaxt and have different functions then sql server. I don't know any advanced tutorials for nither.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the date from the ssn column to calculate the age, assuming your described format "1111111111 (DDMMYYXXXX)". However the format string DDMMYY won't easily convert by itself so we need to flip it around into a format the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) function will recognise

Something like this:

```
convert(date, substring(Users.SSN , 17, 2) + substring(Users.SSN , 15, 2) + substring(Users.SSN , 13, 2), 12)
```

From there its a simple matter to [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189794.aspx) the age.

Be aware that SQL Server will treat the years 00 to 49 as this century. Which might be an issue for older folk...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a UDF for converting the CPR to a `date` which will make your life easier with doing analysis in the future and you test it more easily. This version addresses the century issue that @paul-bambury mentioned by assuming nobody is more than 100 years old.

```
create function dbo.birthdate_from_cpr(@cpr varchar(10))
returns date
as
begin
  declare @year char(2) = substring(@cpr, 5, 2),
          @month char(2) = substring(@cpr, 3, 2),
          @day char(2) = substring(@cpr, 1, 2),
          @century char(2)

  -- if the current 2 digit year is less than the birthday year, assume it was last century
  -- e.g. 76 should be 1976 but 02 should be 2002
  if right(datepart(yy, getdate()), 2) < @year
    set @century = left(datepart(yy, getdate()) - 100, 2)
  else
    set @century = left(datepart(yy, getdate()), 2)


  return convert(date, @century + @year + @month + @day, 120)
end
go

select dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('1312761234'),
       dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('0101041234'),
       age = datediff(yy, dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('1312761234'), getdate())
```

Comment: would you please also write a query , im not quite understand with UDF :)